# pointer query in dereferencing

Tags: c++, pointers

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef int uint32_t;

uint8_t Local_Buffer[2] = {1,3};

uint32_t d_buffer;

d_buffer = ( *(uint32_t *)Local_Buffer );
```

What is the content of `d_buffer` in the end? After printing value of d_buffer, i get 0x70820301. So its an address.

Comment: The question is what you are trying to do with this code? Do you want to understand pointers/ typedefs / casting ?. The latter is fine and you can easily find more good repsonses if you ask so

Answer (score 5):

You're setting up a local buffer of 2 bytes with the values 1, 3, like this:

```
|0x01|0x03|
```

Then you're casting that value (using `C`-style casts) to a pointer to a `uint32_t`, dereferencing that and stroing the result.  `uint32_t` is 4 bytes in size.

Logically, it may seem that you are getting `d_buffer` to have some values like:

```
|0x01|0x03|?|?
```

In reality, this cast reads past the ends of an array, and therefore evokes undefined behavior, so literally *anything* could happen.

In your particular case, it appears you're getting `d_buffer` populated with the expected values (0x03,0x01) along with two other "random" values from the adjacent memory address.

The [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your architecture will tell you how the individual bytes are stored to make up the value of your `uint32_t` value.  Your value of `0x70820301` shows that `0x0301` are stored as expected, along with the "unexpected" garbage values of `0x70820000`.

Comment: +1, Suggestion: use hex values in showing the memory contents... and the endianness to explain how the OP gets `0x7082` and `0x03` and `0x01`

Answer (score 2):

`( *(uint32_t *)Local_Buffer );` here `Local_Buffer` decays to `unsigned char*`, which points to the first element of the array. You are casting it to `int*` and then de-referencing it. You code has **Undefined Behavior**, since the array is of size 2, where an `int` has in most platform atleast size 4. Accessing it as `int` will pass beyond the memory, and what will happen while accessing that memory is **undetermined**.

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour for reasons far simpler and more profound than you insinuate.

Comment: After printing value of d_buffer, i get 0x70820301. So its an address.

Comment: @KerrekSB, may be I am overlooking something. Would you plz post some further details?

Comment: @learningfellow, it is surely not an address. I get some negative values, but anything can happen in undefined scenarios.

Comment: @learningfellow: That's not an address. It's the result of interpreting four bytes of memory as a 32-bit integer. Notice that the lower two bytes (01 and 03) are the two byte values in the array; the others are garbage that was sitting after the array. And of course, as others have said, accessing that garbage gives undefined behaviour, so in principle anything could happen.

Comment: @learningfellow, plz avoid commenting for thanks. if any answer/comment seems useful, upvote it and accept the answer which most accurately solves your problem.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: It's simply UB to access an object through a glvalue that is not of its actual type. Any details of why it might not work are irrelevant. The mere attempt to do so is UB.